# Box2D:How to make a body ignore gravity

Tags: c++, box2d, gravity

I have set the gravity of my world as follows

```
world=new b2World(b2Vec2(0.0,9.8));
```

I have a dynamic body called `b2Body* sta1` which is falling from the top of the screen. And I have another dynamic body `sta2` which should not fall i.e it just move on some keypress. The problem is how can I give this body of my world zero gravity i.e is there any way to give different gravity values to different bodies in the world?

Comment: You again :) Do you ever use google? http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/custom-gravity

Comment: aah thats embarassing! I need to learn how to google stuff!!

Comment: Okay so I need to do this:

`bodydef.gravityScale = 0.0f;`

Am i right?

Comment: well... if it worked, then you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you are right. You should set the gravity scale of the body defition.

```
   sta2def.gravityScale = 0.0f;
```